# stuck in Go parallel testing (automation test which connect with microservices)

Tags: go, integration-testing, microservices, sleep, thread-sleep

I am running a parallel test using `go test`. It's a scenario-based test and test runs based on provided JSON data.

Sample JSON data looks like below

```
[
 {
   ID: 1,
   dependency: []
   ...
 },
 {
   ID: 2
   dependency: [1]
   ...
 },
 {
   ID: 3
   dependency: [2]
   ...
 },
 {
   ID: 4
   dependency: [1,2]
   ...
 }
]
```

Here ID is identifier of a testcase and dependency is referring to the testcases which should run before a testcase.

Circular dependency checker is implemented and it's making sure that no circular dependency is on JSON.

Test code look like below.

```
    t.Run(file, func(t *testing.T) {
        t.Parallel()
        var tcs []TestCase
        bytes := ReadFile(file, t)
        json.Unmarshal(bytes, &tcs)

        CheckCircularDependencies(tcs, t) // check circular dependency graph

        for idx, tc := range tcs {
            queues = append(queues, queitem{
                idx:             idx
                stepID:          step.ID,
                status:          NotStarted,
                ....
            })
        }
        for idx, tc := range tcs {
            UpdateWorkQueStatus(tc, InProgress, t)
            ProcessQueItem(tc, t)
        }
    })

func ProcessQueItem(tc TestCase, t *testing.T) {
        WaitForDependencies(tc, t) // this waits for all the dependency test cases to be finished

        ...
        // DO TEST code which takes about 2-3s
        // Provide a command to microservices
        // Wait for 1-2s for the command to be processed
        // If not processed within 1-2s then wait again for 1-2s
        // Once command is processed, just check the result and finish test case

        UpdateWorkQueStatus(tc, Done, t)
    })
}

func WaitForDependencies(tc TestCase, t *testing.T) {
    if !GoodToGoForTestCase(tc, t) {
        SleepForAWhile()
        WaitForDependencies(tc, t)
    }
}

func SleepForAWhile() {
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

**Parallel test Behavior:**
This is working as expected on my personal computer which has multiple processors.
But when it is working on Google Cloud (maybe 1 cpu), it's stuck and does not go ahead at all for 10mins.

**Current solution:**
Running tests without parallelism and doing by the order of IDs. (just removed `t.Parallel()` function call to avoid parallelism)

**Problem:**
This serial solution is taking more than 3 times than parallel solution, since most of testing time is based on sleeping time.
The test code itself also contains sleep function call.

**My question**
1. Is this architecture correct and can work correctly on 1 processor CPU?
2. If this architecture can work, what will be the problem of stuck?

Comment: We can't talk about parallelism if you have 1 CPU nor when you have to execute tasks in a specific order.